# Implementing kafka consumer in spark-1.0

Tags: intellij-idea, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I need to implement kafka consumer in spark streaming for spark 1.0 . I have written a kafka producer. Can anyone please help me on how to write a spark receiver for pulling the messages from kafka? Also, May I please know how to run kafka spark streaming project in Intellij IDEA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spark streaming comes with its own consumer.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

And in the official repository exists some [examples](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/) for streaming and a wordcount for [kafka](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/KafkaWordCount.scala).

In intellij just import spark-streaming and spark-streaming-kafka modules and write a simple main like the example.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/dibbhatt/kafka-spark-consumer

> ..
>   This utility will help to pull messages from Kafka Cluster using Spark
>   Streaming. The Kafka Consumer is Low Level Kafka Consumer (
>   SimpleConsumer) and have better handling of the Kafka Offsets and
>   handle failures
>   ..

And according to [this blog post](http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2014/10/01/kafka-spark-streaming-integration-example-tutorial/),

> provides better replaying control in case of downstream failures (e.g. Spark machines died).

Answer (score 1):

use KafkaUtils.createStream();

Here's the API: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.2/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/streaming/kafka/KafkaUtils.html